# How do I get the drive mapping to work via GPO after a domain rename?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, mappeddrive

I just underwent a domain rename as requested by management.

So previously I had my network shares put under GPO.

They were all under `Update`, using the `reconnect` option and were using the FQDN of the network share.
E.g. `\\server.contoso.com\share$`

So the new domain is something like `ad.contoso.com` so I changed all the mappings to e.g. `\\server.ad.contoso.com\share$`

However, on updating the policies from the user's side, I noticed that the mapped drives still point to the old FQDN.

Is there a way to correct this?

The reason why I am using FQDN is that some of the users are using VPN and it seems to work better when they are off-site compared to just the computer name.

Comment: Use the Replace option instead of the Update option.

Comment: @joeqwerty Replace does not seem to be working on the clients. They still point to the old FQDN after calling a gpupdate /force on the client followed by a log off.